# check the Number of connection open for database

Tags: asp.net, connection-pooling, pool

I am trying to implement the Connection Pool in my project. I need to count the number of connection that i need at a particular time so that i can set the maximum limit of connection for connection pool. Can any one guide me how can i check, how many connections are using at a particular time.

Comment: Why do you want to implement your own connection-pool if there's [already one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)?

Comment: i am not trying to implement another Connection pool but i just want to know that how many connections are opened at a particular time. Means i want some graphical representation that at this point the connection usage was more and at this point it was low. So that i can set the maximum and minimum limit of connection pool in web.config.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: I am using Sql Server 2008

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/216020/284240 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487671/get-number-of-open-connection-string-in-my-application